# Oracle joins Vs Informatica Joins

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I have two Tables  A(master) and B (detail)

in oracle : A right join B --> Matched records from both + Non matched from Right
A left  join B --> Matched records from both + Non matched from Left

so what is the equivalent output in informatica ?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle and Informatica outer joins works in similar way.
In oracle - 'master' right join 'detail' means all matching + non matching from 'detail'
In informatica Joiner Transformation, refer to join type in properties,

- A'Master' outer join means all matching + non matching from 'detail' B
- 'Detail' outer join means all matching + non matching from 'master' A
- 'Full' outer join means all matching + non matching from 'detail' B+ non matching from 'master' A

[image]

Comment: In Informatica Master table is Right table or Left table ?

Comment: Whatever you drop into JNR first, it becomes detail and other table becomes master. Now, rule of thumb is set table with less column, less data as master. Because informatica caches master first.

Answer (score 0):

**Master outer join:** In Master outer join, **all rows** from the `Detail` source are returned by the join and **only matching** rows from the `Master` source are returned.

**Detail outer join:** In detail outer join, **only matching** rows are returned from the `Detail` source, and **all rows** from the `Master` source are returned.

**Full outer join:** In full outer join, **all records** from both the sources are returned. Master outer and Detail outer joins are equivalent to left outer joins in SQL.

**Normal join:** In normal join **only matching rows** are returned from both the sources